# Pytorch: torch.int32 to torch.long

Tags: python, types, pytorch

I'm new in stackoverflow, hope this post respects all the requirements.

As in the tile, I was wondering how to change the type of a data from torch.int32 to torch.long, as I obtain this error in my code:

ValueError: Argument `edge_index` needs to be of type `torch.long` but found type `torch.int32`.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's the context the error pops out? [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

There are two easy ways to convert tensor data to torch.long and they do the same thing. Check the below snippet.

```
# Example tensor
a = torch.tensor([1, 2, 3], dtype = torch.int32)

# One Way
a = a.to(torch.long)

# Second Way
a = a.type(torch.long)

# Test it out (Should print long version of dtype)
print(a.dtype)
```

Sarthak Jain